# Add missing column keys

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, functional-style

**Example** data:

```
data = {{"1", 50}, {"1", 60}, {"1", 40}, {"2", 15}, {"3", 18}, {"3", 18}};
```

The first entry in each pair is a row number and the second a value.
Row numbers always start with "1", and there are no gaps between rows. There can be up to 26 columns using labels in the {"A" ... "Z"} - range. The result should only use the minumum number of column labels necessary for the given data set.

With this example the result should look like:

```
result =
  <|"1" -> <|"A" -> 50, "B" -> 60, "C" -> 40|>,
   "2" -> <|"A" -> 15, "B" -> Missing[_], "C" -> Missing[_]|>,
   "3" -> <|"A" -> 18, "B" -> 18, "C" -> Missing[_]|>|>;
```

and display as

```
Dataset @ result
```

[image]

The solution I found is too convoluted. Answers should avoid, if possible,
loops and counters (i++).

How would you go from `data` to `result`?

Comment: Why do you use `Missing[_]` instead of just `Missing[]`?

Comment: No particular reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
allkeys = Take[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], Max@Counts@data[[All, 1]]]; 

reduce = Query[allkeys]@AssociationThread[allkeys[[;; Length@#]], #] &;

GroupBy[data, First -> Last, reduce]
```

[image]

```
Dataset @ %
```

[image]

You can also use

```
Merge[reduce] @ MapApply[Rule] @ data
```

> same result

Comment: thank you @eldo; fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

In stages:

```
data = {{"1", 50}, {"1", 60}, {"1", 40}, {"2", 15}, {"3", 18}, {"3", 18}};

grouped = GroupBy[data, First -> Last];
(* <|1->{50,60,40},2->{15},3->{18,18}|> *)

result = AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"} -> PadRight[#, 3, Missing[_]]] & /@ grouped
```

This only handles 3 columns. To be dynamic up to 26 columns:

```
MakeDataset[data : {{_, _} ..}] :=
  With[
    {grouped = GroupBy[data, First -> Last]},
    With[
      {columnCount = Max[Length /@ grouped]},
      With[
        {columnLabels = ToUpperCase[Take[Alphabet[], columnCount]]},
        AssociationThread[columnLabels -> PadRight[#, columnCount, Missing[]]] & /@ grouped]]]
```

Usage:

```
MakeDataset[data]
(* <|1-><|A->50,B->60,C->40|>,
     2-><|A->15,B->Missing[],C->Missing[]|>,
     3-><|A->18,B->18,C->Missing[]|>|> *)
```

Comment: I don't agree - row 1 has three entries, so you get columns A, B and C. If row 1 had a 4th entry, you must and can get columns A, B, C and D. With other words: The column letters have to be computed.

Comment: You said "I have the following data". I interepreted that to mean that this was your actual data. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - I changed the question as to this regard.

Comment: Based on your second paragraph, I could have inferred that you wanted generality. I was keying off of how definitive your statements like "I have the following data" and  "the result should look like". I could have read it again to resolve the contradiction. But oh well, we understand each other now.

Comment: Yes, +1 now for your nice solution

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{"1", 50}, {"1", 60}, {"1", 40}, {"1", 65}, {"2", 15}, {"3", 
   18}, {"3", 18}}

h = PadRight[Map[Last] /@ #, {Length@#, Max@(Length /@ #)}, 
    Missing[]] &@GatherBy[data, First]

k = ConstantArray[
  ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[1 ;; Last@Dimensions@h]]
  , {First@Dimensions@h}]

m = (AssociationThread /@ Thread[k -> h])

ds=Association@MapIndexed[
  AssociationThread[ToString@First@#2 -> #1] &
  , m
  ]

Dataset[ds]
```

[image]

Comment: slightly simpler way to get `h`: `PadRight[GatherBy[data, First][[All, All, 2]], Automatic, Missing[]]`

Comment: Much appreciated @kglr.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this transformation in Mathematica by grouping the data by the first element and then creating an association that maps the letters "A", "B", "C", etc., to the respective numbers. If there are not enough numbers for a key, you should append `Missing[]` to fill in the gaps.

```
data = {{"1", 50}, {"1", 60}, {"1", 40}, {"1", 999}, {"2", 15}, {"3", 
    18}, {"3", 19}};

transformData[data_] := 
 Module[{grouped, letters, maxLen}, 
  grouped = GroupBy[data, First -> Last];
  maxLen = Max[Length /@ grouped];
  letters = Take[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], maxLen];
  KeySort@
   AssociationMap[
    Function[key, 
     AssociationThread[letters, 
      PadRight[grouped[key], maxLen, Missing[]]]], Keys[grouped]]]

result = transformData[data]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwDIbveQqRs0eXbR3LSke7je6wBkrb00wYIvES08QptgMtJc@eKW6aDqbTZ/mX9Esl2lyUaGWCbZuiRZjC6eQHPoPxbcPgjI9XfLhiGIaO74iDscN7Qg8ogqfhHYRNM/E8q1GZn0qX7zSFd6O@Y3iekjyq0roQ/JTpqt6LlEEhrBXaMCjxsBSqcT37X/L30dHr0fVgsJDaWLh5gSUaG09Iea4iYYQHTpTZHEazSwMn6SeQZos7wd9y1JhQZo0qE9yfk23/y48vDlzNpzhuKm1n3X5zY6pE0tkqFeGeu5UXtUq6BN@JY3@Fv7ptrgWmfNjtLIAVpmuZ5Zb39rrqYS6DSBojVcZjCtZZMBchJTxPC1MXltb4f90YRqOVlsq27S8)